# How to grant access to hosts.txt file using C++ 11 on MacOS

Tags: c++, macos, permissions

I am attempting to write a program that can append text to a given host file on MacOS, but due to permission issues I am not allowed to do so.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    std::ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("/private/etc/hosts.txt", std::ios::app);


    if(!myfile.is_open()){
        std::cout << "Host file could not be opened or located" << std::endl;
    } else {
        myfile << "data to be appended" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Host file has been modified" << std::endl;
        myfile.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I created a public folder with a mock of the hosts.txt file in the same root directory and it worked so I'm positive it is a permission error but I am BRAND new to working with files in C++ and have no idea how to proceed or if what I'm doing is even possible.

Thanks

Comment: System files are not writable (and sometimes not readable) by users, you need elevated ("root") privileges to do it. It have nothing to do with C++, it's an operating system feature, and it's there for your own safety. If this is part of a school assignment or exercise, the classes should have included information about how to elevate your privilege so you could do it. Otherwise, please tell us *why* you want to do this? What is the actual problem you need to solve? And why do you have to do it through a C++ program?

Comment: Sure, not a school problem. I am attempting to make a program that essentially blocks certain adult sites (for nofap movement) by appending something like "127.0.0.1 www.sitenamehere.com" to a host file. I'm doing it to mainly further develop my coding skills in C++. Is there a way I could obtain elevated privileges so I could make modifications to hosts.txt? I learned about chmod to modify permissions but I only used that in terminal, never a C++ app.

Comment: @ericsaddy Could `iptables` be an option?

Comment: @TedLyngmo would that be something I could use in conjunction with this app I'm working on or separately? The idea is for me to try and build a simple app with functionality, thats why I ask.

Comment: If you have `root` privs, sure. I made a blocking service on my home server that way. Works fine.

Comment: But see that is what I don't understand.. I am running this application in xcode from my account (an admin account with root access) so shouldn't it work already?

Comment: No, you need to make sure that every kernel service gets the updated info. Your approach would work if every ip-service re-read the hosts file for every request though. (not sure about the `/private` part of it - is that a Mac thing?)

Comment: Just run your program with sudo?